# Is there a way to login to a network without a GUI?

Tags: networking, login

My campus network requires me to login to the campus network with id and password, before allowing me to connect to the internet. The problem is I want to do this without using DE, I want to do this with linux server, is there any way to do it?

Sorry I should've clarified further, so when I connect to my network campus, it opens up a browser and then there is a login form with username and password, and then I fill my credentials and clicked the login button to finally be able to access the internet

Comment: Please, explain how do you log into your campus network using GUI for make me better understand login process: Do you use login and password to wifi access point or any other access point to network? Which protocol you need to use to connect your server to network?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified further, so when I connect to my network campus, it opens up a browser and then there is a login form with username and password, and then I fill my credentials and clicked the login button to finally be able to access the internet

Comment: I guess  proxy server with authorization is using. Here is the good article how to configure proxy with authentication for ``apt`` command. https://thewireframecommunity.com/node/29  If this help, you can configure other type of access for your server by analogy.

Comment: You can likely emulate the process with a script around `wget`/`curl` commands. Developer tools in a GUI browser should show you what URLs are called with what parameters.

Comment: What you are referring to is usually referred to as a *captive portal* I think: see for example [How use a captive portal when in text mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464843/how-use-a-captive-portal-when-in-text-mode)

Comment: @steeldriver That Lynx is interesting, I will try it out tomorrow when I'm at campus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is the one that works for me, I use this eventhough it takes quite a while to connect. https://github.com/systematicat/hack-captive-portals